# Phone number being inserted as 2147483647 into database

Tags: php, mysql, integer

All phone numbers I am trying to enter into my database are being inserted as `2147483647`.

The database field is an `integer(11)`.

Before the phone number is inserted, it goes through the following code  in order to remove all spaces, dashes, and brackets:

```
if (!empty($hphone)) $phone = $hphone;
else if (!empty($HomePhone)) $phone = $HomePhone;
else if (!empty($Phone1)) $phone = $Phone1;
$phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
```

Why is it inserting the phone number as `2147483647` every time, no matter what the phone number is?

Comment: Store phone number as a string (`varchar`), not as an integer.

Comment: @zerkms That obviously isn't going to solve his problem

Comment: @Damien Black: what your assumption is based on?

Comment: @scarhand Can you show the code where $hphone gets set?

Comment: I think the issue is that it is trying to store it as a string, despite it being an integer. Would removing single quotes from the value in the insertion query correct this issue, or do I need to cast it as an integer via PHP?

Comment: @scarhand: the issue is that signed integer max positive value is `2^31 - 1`

Comment: zerkms, I think you just hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Are you planning to subtract one telephone number from another?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you can, convert the phone number to a VARCHAR field, don't store it as a signed (or unsigned) numeric value (int, bigint, double, etc...).

In this case, the limit for signed INT in MySQL of 2147483647 is what is causing your issue.  Anything larger inserted into this field will be capped at that maximum value.

For example the phone number 555-555-5555 if bigger than that limit  (5555555555 >2147483647), as such storing it would result in the max value 2147483647.

I also recommend not storing it as a BIG INT or any other numeric type.  How will you handle extension or special encoded characters like:

```
   +02 112020 10020  
   1-333-232-9393 x203
```

BTW: don't know if the first  is real non-US number format, but you get the idea

Also, phone numbers with relevant leading 0's would be have some of it lost no mater how large the number:

```
 021-392-9293
```

Would be the number 213929293

Comment: "Anything larger will be capped at that" --- ... unless you set a stricter `sql_mode`

Comment: @zerkms good point, it could just reject it, but many don't like that level of strictness.

Comment: indeed. There are too many people that prefer "rubbish data" over "no data" :-)

Comment: Yeah, I've changed it to a VARCHAR. This makes total sense. Thank you, zerkms, and everyone else who has contributed.

Comment: @scarhand thanks, feel free to mark it correct, I'm so close to 10K reputation.  I hear a magical portal opens up and a unicorn comes out to play 'Go' and drink tea with me...

Comment: @Ray Awww, I missed out somehow! I didn't even see *one* unicorn! :-P +1, almost there

Comment: @Ray, the standard for international phone directory number display is very close to what you have.  North American numbers are like `+1.212.555.1212` where the country code is preceded by a +.  A UK number might be `+44.800.999.9999` for example

Comment: Thanks dear.. It's really helping me a lot @ray

Comment: this post just saved my butt dealing with shopify API product ID's

Answer (score 1):

if you want to store it as a number use bigint because int has it's max value equal to 2147483647.

So whatever number you try to store that is higher than 2147483647 will be stored as 2147483647.

Here is some reference for mysql types:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing this type of problem and I have solved that problem after
updating datatype From 'INT' TO 'BIGINT'.

Answer (score -1):

Change Mobile no type from int to varchar in mysql.

Comment: This seems to duplicate existing answers.